# Iterating in depth of json object React.js-redux,

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-redux

I have a JSON object stored in Redux, I have to display all the `titles{ As LINKS}` when clicking on the title it displays its `section:[....](AS  TITLE{LINKS})` and iterating in depth until `JSONOBJECT.section.type===menu` and display all the section's title. And if `section.type==="Vid"` then it's an Anchor tag only.

On clicking the back button load the previousState/props as it was on the previous page using `Redux`.

Snap of JSON object:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbYru.png

Explanation:
I have loaded the root level section on a component named `DASHBOARD.js` and on clicking any title I want to load the subSections on the same `DASHBOARD.js` and on clicking the `BACK` button load the previous superSection.

```
{
    "id":"",
 "section":[
   {
    "id":"",
 "section":[{
    "id":"",
 "section":[{
    "id":"",
 "section":[{
    "id":"",
 "section":[],
 "title":"",
 "type":"Vid"
},{
    "id":"",
 "section":[],
 "title":"",
 "type":"Vid"
},{
    "id":"",
 "section":[],
 "title":"",
 "type":"Vid"
},{
    "id":"",
 "section":[],
 "title":"",
 "type":"Vid"
}],
 "title":"",
 "type":"menu"
}],
 "title":"",
 "type":"menu"
},{
    "id":"",
 "section":[],
 "title":"",
 "type":"Vid"
},{
    "id":"",
 "section":[],
 "title":"",
 "type":"Vid"
},{
    "id":"",
 "section":[],
 "title":"",
 "type":"Vid"
}],
 "title":"",
 "type":"menu"
},{
    "id":"",
 "section":[{
    "id":"",
 "section":[],
 "title":"",
 "type":"Vid"
},{
    "id":"",
 "section":[],
 "title":"",
 "type":"Vid"
},{
    "id":"",
 "section":[],
 "title":"",
 "type":"Vid"
},{
    "id":"",
 "section":[],
 "title":"",
 "type":"Vid"
}],
 "title":"",
 "type":"menu"
},{
    "id":"",
 "section":[{
    "id":"",
 "section":[],
 "title":"",
 "type":"Vid"
},{
    "id":"",
 "section":[],
 "title":"",
 "type":"Vid"
},{
    "id":"",
 "section":[],
 "title":"",
 "type":"Vid"
},{
    "id":"",
 "section":[],
 "title":"",
 "type":"Vid"
}],
 "title":"",
 "type":"menu"
},{
    "id":"",
 "section":[{
    "id":"",
 "section":[],
 "title":"",
 "type":"Vid"
},{
    "id":"",
 "section":[],
 "title":"",
 "type":"Vid"
},{
    "id":"",
 "section":[],
 "title":"",
 "type":"Vid"
},{
    "id":"",
 "section":[],
 "title":"",
 "type":"Vid"
}],
 "title":"",
 "type":"menu"
}
   ],
 "title":"",
 "type":"menu"
}
```

Sample View of what the project would look like:

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3f5f.png
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnb00.png
3. https://i.stack.imgur.com/705ni.png

Firstly I clicked on any `Navigation` item. Then it would load its `contentTitle[image:1]` as in the given image, and all titles would be `<Link>`.Then on clicking that link,  it would Load the `childContentTitle<Link>[image:2]`, and on clicking that `childContentTitle` it would load  `grandchildContentTitle`, and then `grandgrandchild[image:3]` and so on. Then, this all will be re-render on the same `reactComponent` named Dashboard until `JSON.type!=="vid`.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. For your question, it will be better if you write down the sample of json object instead of taking screenshot. Also, you can provide your react code that read and display the json or any attempt of yours to read the data.

Comment: Actually I have a very complex json object , and i have  simplified it ,so my  React code is not appropriate for this  json object.

Comment: maybe DFS or BFS is something you could implement to search your menu item.

Comment: I was thinking That  react may help me in  some way as it  works with state, props and store. So it might store  prev. state  somewhere or helps me in maintaining prev. State.

Comment: @blaz  Can you look at this??